# Grafana:change the role of an existing user

Tags: prometheus, grafana, grafana-variable, grafana-api

I have created few Grafana users using `curl` command. Here is the command i used.

```
curl -XPOST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "name":"user1@graf.com",
  "email":"user1@graf.com",
  "password":"userpassword",
  "role": "Admin"
}' http://admin:admin@grafana01.default.svc.cluster.local:3000/api/admin/users
```

Now i want to change the role from `Admin` to `Viewer`.  How can i do that?. is there any other way I can try this out?. Any help is appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

To update the role to viewer for instance you can do this:

```
curl -XPATCH -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "role":"Viewer"
}' http://admin:admin@grafana01.default.svc.cluster.local:3000/api/orgs/:orgId/users/:userId
```

Be sure to use the right orgId and userId

Have a look at
https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/11945

EDIT: I edited my previous (and wrong) answer.